# SQL server inserting multiple row Id stays the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an insert query in SQL server inside my stored procedure.

The table has 3 fields `ID, TileID, CountryID`, here TileID and CountryID are getting from other tables and `ID` is incremented by selecting the max(ID) from the table.

My query:

```
declare @TileSId int
SET @TileSId= (SELECT isnull(max(Id),0)+1 from tilesorting)

insert [fiesauthentication].[dbo].tilesorting (Id,TileId,Nationality)

select @TileSId,t.Id,wc.CountryID from WebstoreCountry wc
left join tile t on t.URL = wc.URL AND t.CompanyId = wc.CompanyID
```

Here if I have multiple rows in the select then the ID is the same for each, I need the ID to increase on each row.

My output:

[image]

I want it like below

[image]

Comment: Show the full code that does the insert. I suspect it's because you're inserting a set of rows after calculating the ID once, so the set all get the same ID

Comment: Incidentally, select max(ID) +1 is a terrible way of generating an increment in number. SQL server has a built in auto increment facility, why are you not using it?

Comment: @CaiusJard The table is created by another person and I am not authorized to change it

Comment: No actual insert is shown -- are you talking about the second `SELECT` statement? Either way, you are defining a single value and applying it across multiple rows. As @CaiusJard says, why are you not using built-in auto increment in the table?

Comment: This can be done, but it is a BAD idea generally. If you generate this value in your SELECT statements, then this value will change every time you run your SELECT. And if it changes, then it really isn't functionally an ID.

Comment: @MurrayW added my insert query, is it possible now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this. This will get the last inserted `id` from the table then create `row_number()` for each new generated row. By adding them you'll get the new Incremented number as you need.

```
Begin Try
    Begin Transaction t1
      declare @TileSId int
      SET @TileSId= (SELECT isnull(max(Id),0)+1 from tilesorting WITH (TABLOCKX))
        ;with cte as 
        (
            select row_number() over (order by t.id) as Slno,t.Id,wc.CountryID 
            from WebstoreCountry wc
            left join tile t on t.URL = wc.URL AND t.CompanyId = wc.CompanyID 
        )
        Insert into tilesorting ( colid, col2 )
        select @TileSId + Slno , CountryID from cte
    commit transaction t1
End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback transaction t1
End Catch
```

Here we use transaction to lock your table for further use. You may find this link for more info about Transaction in SQL [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @CaiusJard: can you please explain how? Here OP already said that change in table structure is not possible.

Comment: If you insist on working a max+1 solution then at least lock the entire table so multiple simultaneous insets don't insert clashing IDs ; we already know this "id" column isn't constrained to be unique.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Ya not locking table in this type of code was my fault, corrected it. Thanks

Comment: A transaction doesn't lock the table unless you add `with (tablockx)` to the query, and its not getting the max value inside the transaction anyway.